# creating object of pojo with integer

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

Inside a `POJO` I am trying to create a private object of `POJO` using an integer.

I have tried `@JSONAlias`, `@Field` and `@TypeAlias`, I also tried adding different dependencies.

```
public class Abc {
    private String name;
    //I am getting error here. I want to map few values present in Ids against 123 object. But I am not able to do so.
    private Ids 123;
}
```

In my `MongoDb` I should be able to map the values as shown below

```
"123"{
    "id1":"453",
    "id2":"859",
    "id3":"839"
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i think you need to have array of Ids
something like: private Ids[] ids;
check your variable name as well. it should be a valid identifier

Comment: Assuming your first code snippet is supposed to be a Java class, then "123" is not a valid identifier like "name" is, therefore this is a compiler error. The next best valid identifier is something like "_123"

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow you to declare field name which starts with numbers.
For your requirement, you can use @JsonProperty("123") to your POJO field

Comment: a small correction: Java doesn't allow you to declare field name WHICH STARTS FROM numbers.

Comment: So there might be some solution for this case right? Thats what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

What is your error content?
And I think your field name 123 is not good. It should not start with a number.

Comment: My requirement is same:
I want the values to get stored in DB as below,

"123":{
"id1":"5354",
"id2":"2323",
"id3":"3252"

}